# PHP mail line breaks not always working

Tags: php, line-breaks

I have a script that sends mail but sometimes the line breaks work and other times they do not. I have no idea what causes them to break and how to resolve.

This is an example of the type of code I have

```
$message .= "Name: ".$_POST['name'] . "\r\n";
$message .= "E-mail Address: ".$_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
$message .= "Telephone Number: ".$_POST['telephone'] . "\r\n";
$message .= "Subject: ".$_POST['subject'] . "\r\n";
$message .= "Message: ".$_POST['message']. "\r\n";
$message .= "=========================\r\n";
```

Comment: Try using normal library and not using standard PHP `mail()` function. i.e. http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: Mail client and operating system interpret that differently.

Comment: Send a HTML email and use <br /> ?

Comment: Agreed with @Eugene; I would recommend everyone to use a decent library like swiftmailer or phpMailer instead of the built-in php mail() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a huge issue with line endings specially when you pass it as a message and even more specially, when you pass it to [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

So as I said in comment, better user normal library and I would personally recommend [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). It is now under the wing of such developer as `Fabien Potencier`, who is main author behind Symfony2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send mail using swiftmailer or PHPMailer. Here is a good tutorial to use PHPMailer

http://rohitashv.wordpress.com/2013/01/19/how-to-send-mail-using-php/